# Is there a limit in the size of String in Android app?

Tags: android, json, string, kotlin, gson

I used Gson Library to convert Json file into Objects. When I did it on Kotlin project independent from Android, it worked and I got my objects. But when I did the same thing in my android project, I noticed that the string gotten didn't contain all the file data.

Here is the code in the android project :

```
val inputStream = context.assets.open("test.json")
val inputString = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
val jsonData = Gson().fromJson(inputString, TestArray::class.java)
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: No there's not, but there's a limit on how many characters the debugger shows for a string, you may be on this issue

Comment: True !! The debugger shows a limited number of characters, I didn't think about it, because on Intellij idea debugger I didn't face this issue. Now I can focus in the real issue. Thank you very much !!!